# Multiply UITextfields values with Double in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to Multiply

```
self.tipLable.text = String("\((enterBillAmountTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue * (middleTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue * (0.01))")
```

But getting error Binary operator * cannot be applied to operands of type Int and Double

I am taking values form UITextfields. How to do this multiplication?

Comment: Why are you casting it to `NSString` instead of going straight for the  `Double`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
extension Double {

    // Convert Double to currency
    var currency: String {
        let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2

        return formatter.stringFromNumber(self) ?? "0"
    }
} 

tipLable.text = [enterBillAmountTextField, middleTextField].reduce(0.01) { $0 * (Double($1.text!) ?? 0) }.currency
```

A slightly shorter and clearer solution. Added a "currency" extension so it can still be done in one line :).

Comment: Nice touch with the rounding ;)

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
self.tipLable.text = String("\( Double((enterBillAmountTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue) * Double((middleTextField.text! as NSString).integerValue) * 0.01)")
```

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to NSString ? You can use `Int(enterBillAmountTextField.text!) ?? 0` or `Double(enterBillAmountTextField.text!) ?? 0`

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't know how to multiply an Int and a Double.  Should the result be an Int or a Double?

Swift won't do implicit type conversion between different operands.

If you want your result to be a Double, both operands should be a Double.  Then convert the Double to a String.

While this can all be concisely expressed in one single very long line, perhaps it's more readable and maintainable if you break it out into separate lines:

```
let subTotal = Double(billAmountTextField.text!) ?? 0
let percent = (Double(middleTextField.text!) ?? 0) * 0.01
let tip = subTotal * percent
self.tipLable.text = String(format: "%.2f", tip) // Handle rounding
```

Answer (score -1):

> The answer you gave is going to bring nightmare to you in some moment.

Try to keep yourself doing things in a way you can guarantee that you are going to be able to test it and that you/or others are going to be able to understand what you are doing there.

```
/**
  Use this function to calculate tip, useful for later testing

 - returns: Double Value of the tip you should give
 */
func calculateTip(billAmount billAmount:Double, middleValue:Double) -> Double {
     /// Actually calculate Tip if everything is OK
    return billAmount * middleValue * 0.01
}
```

> Then in your `@IBAction` make sure you have correct data before asking
>   your function for a tip

```
/// If you have bill data, obtain Double value stored there,
/// if something fails, you should return nil
guard let billAmountText = enterBillAmountTextField.text, billAmount = Double(billAmountText) else {
    return
}
/// If you have middle value data, obtain Double value stored there,
/// if something fails, you should return nil
guard let middleText = middleTextField.text, middleValue = Double(middleText) else {
    return
}
```

> Then you can call that function

```
let tip = calculateTip(billAmount: billAmount, middleValue: middleValue).description
//and return in proper format
tipLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", tip)
```

Comment: so.. Where is the downside?

Comment: Why not pass the amount and tip into the function as parameters, instead of tightly coupling functional code to the UI?

Comment: @PetahChristian Any further improve suggestions?